# How to reset customization of default home view in IBM Cognos 11.0.5 to default welcome page

Tags: customization, cognos

While testing customization of Cognos 11.0.5 I've tried to make a dashboard the default home page following the steps in IBM knowledge center [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ag_manage.doc/c_mng_cust_manage.html#cust_mng_th_rext)

---

On the Views tab of the Managing > Customization slide-out panel, click next to the default home view. You can now browse for a dashboard or report to be the default home view, or you can select a view in the list of home views to be the default home view for all users.

---

It worked well, but I made a dire mistake of replacing the selected dashboard with a newer developed version (copy-to --> overwrite), hence I think the default view is pointing to a no-longer-existing object (different new ID)

Cognos is now throwing error after sign-in that home page cannot be retrieved. I have been able to access it back using URL <webserver_name>:<port_number>/bi/?factoryMode=true

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjM0O.png)
BUT what I'm struggling with is setting the default home page in "**View**" tab of the Managing > Customization back to home or another dashboard, instead, it is now BLANK with no settings to adjust neither "home page" nor "sign-in page" shows up!

I've tried to apply the default "IBM" theme again, restarting Cognos application but no go. the settings seem vanished in the "View" tab! Is there any way to reset the incorrect settings in the content server or the configuration manager?

**Update**: found settings under \ibm\cognos\analytics\configuration\data\flipper\config\global
That has the home page pointing configuration for the dispatcher to the perspective but still missing the "Views" settings from UI, looks it would require product support.

Comment: Confirmed a defect in ver 11.0.5 with IBM support and already it has been fixed in a later version 11.0.13 FP3 as recommendation